# rsync command not found (while backing up Postgresql using barman)

Tags: postgresql, path, rsync, database-backups, barman

I am trying to use `barman` to schedule backups to be taken of my Postgresql database. The IPs of my DB server and backup server (both of which run Cent OS 7.2.1511) is 10.113.12.200 and 10.133.12.205 respectively. After studying Barman's documentation and Postgresql documentation for point-in-archiving, I set up the archiving in Postgresql configuation file as

```
archive_mode = on
wal_level = 'replica'
archive_command = 'rsync --rsync-path=/usr/bin/rsync -a %p barman@10.133.12.205:/var/lib/barman/incoming/my_database/%f'
```

I have also enabled password-less SSH from `postgres@10.113.12.200` to `barman@10.113.12.205` and vice-versa as the Barman docs say.

Below is an excerpt from my `barman.conf`'s DB server section.

```
[my-database]
description = "My Database"
ssh_command = ssh postgres@10.113.12.200
conninfo = host=10.113.12.200 user=postgres
retention_policy_mode = auto
retention_policy = RECOVERY WINDOW OF 7 days
wal_retention_policy = main
```

I'm really very puzzled and confused over this error `sh: rsync command not found`. Now, I know what this error is after reading about on rsync and going through some questions here on SO including this one here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198756/why-is-rsync-not-found

I SSHed to `barman@10.113.12.205` from `postgres@10.113.12.200` to find out the `$PATH`, executed `which rsync` and then only added `--rsync-path` as above. But still this issue. None of my WAL archives are getting copied as a result. Can someone shed some light? I think I miss something fundamental here.

Comment: wouldn't rsync be executed on the master server?  you are saying you've made sure that rsync is there on the barman machine, what about the master?

Comment: It's in /bin on the master. /bin is in PATH.

Comment: Is it in path for postgres user?

Comment: Also what about putting a full path into the archive command?

Comment: You mean specifying it as /bin/sync?

Comment: /bin/rsync yes, just to make sure it's not a path issue